# How to rename of msi file using Visual Studio Installer 2017 in VS 2017

Tags: c#, installation

I want to put version info in file name of msi file. but I don't know how to do. 
My msi version information is as follows.
[image]

I want to change output file name to version info like as 1.0.0.msi.